# перенос размеров с figma на flutter

Tags: flutter, figma, flutter-ui

Есть макет на фигме, шаблон макета(размер экрана), взят под ios и имеет размер 414х896.
Какие есть лайфхаки, чтобы используя размерности в фигме, сделать интерфейс, одинаково выглядящий на android,ios с разными экранами?

Comment: Одинаково выглядеть не будет, ибо не должно: разные девайсы имеют разные размеры экранов. Советую делать под наименьший, и далее прогрессивно добавляя контент (определяя ширину по медиаКвери.оф-контекст.сайз). Строить всегда одинаковое дерево виджетов и масштабировать их - будет явно неуместно, ведь приложение может быть установлено и на HDPI планшетники (кому нужны апскейл-интерфейсы с 340 на 960 и выше? имхо, юзер удалит приложение сразу как увидит такую жуть...).